# How to achieve throughput of 10 samplers per hour with 1 thread

Tags: jmeter

I have to setup multiple thread groups to simulate prod usecase. For one of the scenario, I have to setup

```
Thread count: 1
Throughput: 10 per hour
```

To achieve this, in a thread group, I set "Number of threads" as 1, loop count as infinite and Duration as 3600.

I added constant throughput timer under flow controller.
In constant throughput timer, I can only set "Target Throughput (in samples **per min**).

I have only one HTTP request in the thread group, so I set Target Throughput (in samples per min)  as 0.16 ( as 10/60 = 0.16).

[image]

But the moment I start the test, only one iteration executes, and the test stops.

Please guide me on how to set "Target Throughput" to meet very low throughput. I.e to achieve 10 samples per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [JMeter 4.0](https://info.blazemeter.com/jmeter-4-jmeter-plugins-taurus) there is a timer which better fits your workload model: [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

Example configuration:

[image]